# Using Search Parameters in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, search, parameters

I am working in Access 2010.

I am building a database that lets my organization catalog blank walls in the city --- including their location, what way they face, whether the adjacent lot is vacant or occupied, etc.  This information is stored in a table called WallsMaster.

This is my query.

```
SELECT WallsMaster.StreetAddress, WallsMaster.Zip, WallsMaster.Direction, WallsMaster.LotInfo

FROM WallsMaster

WHERE 

(
((WallsMaster.Zip) Like "*" & [Forms]![Search_Form]![Zip_Search] 
Or 
(WallsMaster.Zip)="" 
Or 
(WallsMaster.Zip) Is Null)

AND 

((WallsMaster.Direction) Like "*" & [Forms]![Search_Form]![Direction_Search] 
Or 
(WallsMaster.Direction)="" 
Or 
(WallsMaster.Direction) Is Null)

AND 

((WallsMaster.LotInfo) Like "*" & [Forms]![Search_Form]![LotInfo_Search] 
Or 
(WallsMaster.LotInfo)="" 
Or 
(WallsMaster.LotInfo) Is Null)
)
;
```

When I enter a value for Zip but leave the other parameters blank, what I want is ***all*** Direction & LotInfo values (including nulls/blanks) ***for that zip only*** (not including nulls/blank Zip values) .  When I enter Direction but leave the others blank, I want all Zip and LotInfo values (including nulls/blanks) for that Direction (not including null/blank Direction values) , and so on for LotInfo.

What I'm getting when I do this includes nulls/blanks for the
parameters I've left blank but also includes nulls/blanks for the
field I've indicated a search parameter for.

ie, if I search for Zip 19130 and leave Direction & LotInfo blank, I get this:

```
Address,Zip,Direction,LotInfo
123 Main St, 19130, South, Vacant
456 Elm St, , North, Vacant
789 Fake St, 19130, , ,
321 K St, 19130, East, Occupied
```

What I want is this:

```
Address, Zip, Direction, LotInfo
123 Main St, 19130, South, Vacant  
789 Fake St, 19130, , 
321 K St,19130, East, Occupied
```

1. How can I re-write my SQL script to give me the results I want?
2. For the sake of this example, I'm just sharing a few fields.  My real WallMaster table has about 30 fields and hundreds of records and I want my search form to search by any/all of these fields at a time.  Is this the most efficient way to write this search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question, I personally wouldn't bother writing a query to filter every conceivable combination of values that you envisage.

[Here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html) is a great example from Allen Browne showing how to implement a search form. I have used this in the past and it works brilliantly, however this was back in the day when Access 2003 was the only available option.

This solution soon becomes unwieldy if you need to add more fields to your table or the business rules change slightly.

Instead, just load your data into a datasheet and utilize the automatic filtering that Microsoft access 2010 offers you out of the box. You will be able to filter all columns in any combination you wish and this will even work if you add new fields to your table (providing the forms data source is set up correctly)

Comment: Thanks - I will look at Allen Brown's method.

Comment: I'm also trying to set up a search form that uses a query to generate results because I then have reports based on those query results.... so it's not just an on-screen datasheet that I want to see.

Comment: Can't you just design your report with the same set of fields as the form and then pass in the same Recordsource & Filter properties to the report?

Comment: Thanks... that would actually work.  I guess I was making this more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

You're testing the wrong thing for being equal to "" or Null. You want to test the *inputs* for that.

```
SELECT WallsMaster.StreetAddress, WallsMaster.Zip, WallsMaster.Direction, WallsMaster.LotInfo
FROM WallsMaster

WHERE 

(

(WallsMaster.Zip) Like "*" & [Forms]![Search_Form]![Zip_Search] 

Or 

([Forms]![Search_Form]![Zip_Search] ="" 

Or 

[Forms]![Search_Form]![Zip_Search] Is Null))

AND 

((WallsMaster.Direction) Like "*" & [Forms]![Search_Form]![Direction_Search]

Or 

([Forms]![Search_Form]![Direction_Search]="" 

Or 

[Forms]![Search_Form]![Direction_Search] Is Null)

AND 

((WallsMaster.LotInfo) Like "*" & [Forms]![Search_Form]![LotInfo_Search]

Or 

([Forms]![Search_Form]![LotInfo_Search]="" 

Or 

[Forms]![Search_Form]![LotInfo_Search] Is Null)

)
```

Comment: Thanks - this works (mostly... I just submitted an edit because a bunch of your brackets/parens were mixed up).   Now that I get the general idea, I'm also looking for a more efficient way to do this with dozens of fields... it really doesn't make sense to write 30 clauses in my SQL statement.  Thank you!

Comment: You're probably better off building up the SQL string dynamically then in VBA code

Answer (score 0):

What about this path ?

```
WHERE WallsMaster.Zip Like "*" & NZ([Forms]![Search_Form]![Zip_Search],"")  
AND (WallsMaster.Direction) Like "*" & NZ([Forms]![Search_Form]![Direction_Search],"")
AND (WallsMaster.LotInfo) Like "*" & Nz([Forms]![Search_Form]![LotInfo_Search],"")
```

Comment: This does not seem to return nulls/blanks